# Python append csv with different values for a common index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Is there a way in python to load a csv, then using one column as an index in addition to a date column, append a third column?

I am using pandas.read_csv to load in a csv. Once I have it loaded in, I want to use one column as an index (a SKU, for example) in addition to a date column to append a third column from one int to a different int in a designated range with the column being appended to be appended based on unused numbers in the range for that particular day. For example if I have one SKU number that gets used on the same day 5 times and the column to be appended has an 'appendable' range of 5-10, is it possible I make the script aware that 5 got used the first time, 6 needs to be used the second time, and 7 the third time, in addition to resetting back to 5 when the SKU is found again on a separate day? I am new to python so I apologize if this is a silly question...

Example input:

| SKU | Date | XValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5678 | 03/13/23 | 2 |
| 5678 | 03/13/23 | 2 |
| 5678 | 03/13/23 | 2 |
| 5678 | 03/13/23 | 2 |
| 5678 | 03/13/23 | 2 |
| 5678 | 03/14/23 | 2 |

Example output:

| SKU | Date | XValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5678 | 03/13/23 | 5 |
| 5678 | 03/13/23 | 6 |
| 5678 | 03/13/23 | 7 |
| 5678 | 03/13/23 | 8 |
| 5678 | 03/13/23 | 9 |
| 5678 | 03/14/23 | 5 |

Does this make sense?

EDIT: For multiple SKUs that have different starting ranges:
Sure, something like this...

Input:

| SKU | Date | Xvalue | Range to be used |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5678 | 03/13/23 | 2 | 5-10 |
| 5678 | 03/13/23 | 2 | 5-10 |
| 3214 | 03/13/23 | 4 | 85-95 |
| 3214 | 03/13/23 | 4 | 85-95 |

Output:

| SKU | Date | Xvalue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5678 | 03/13/23 | 5 |
| 5678 | 03/13/23 | 6 |
| 3214 | 03/13/23 | 85 |
| 3214 | 03/13/23 | 86 |

Also, the range to be used for some SKU's is every other number in the range because it has a subproduct and one of them uses even numbers in the range and one of them uses odd numbers in the range. The range to be used is not a part of the initial dataset but I added that column for clarification.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample input and example output (as text)?

Comment: I am trying to format it as a table with pipes but it isn't saving the actual line format

Comment: you need pipes in the header row and a row of piped dashes

Comment: What should happen if one `XValue` is, for example, `11`? You should probably make example with that possibility...

Comment: Is that going to affect the python code? The xvalue per SKU is almost always going to start out as the same thing... If it is something different, I still want it to be appended the same way as if it were the same. I want to use only the SKU and date as the basis for what range applies to the append.

Comment: So, for every SKU do you have defined from which value it should start?

Comment: Yes, I have a range for every SKU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
# Returns the number of times of the most represented day
mode_count = lambda x: x.value_counts().head(1).squeeze()
df['XValue'] = df.groupby('SKU')['Date'].transform(mode_count)

# Get the cumulative count for each (SKU, Date)
df['XValue'] += df.groupby(['SKU', 'Date']).cumcount()
print(df)

# Output:
    SKU      Date  XValue
0  5678  03/13/23       5
1  5678  03/13/23       6
2  5678  03/13/23       7
3  5678  03/13/23       8
4  5678  03/13/23       9
5  5678  03/14/23       5
```

Comment: I'm not sure, if OP doesn't want simply `df['XValue'] = df.groupby(['SKU', 'Date']).cumcount() + 5` ...

Comment: Awesome, thank you. The one thing I don't see / understand is how it knows to start at 5... Can you please explain this? What if, for example, I wanted it to start at a different number like 80? Every SKU is going to have a different range of numbers to be used, and there are well over 100 different SKUs

Comment: 5 is supposed to be fixed as @AndrejKesely suggested? What do you mean by *Every SKU is going to have a different range of numbers to be used*. Do you have another table for that?